# How to inherit Implementation of pure virtual function C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual, c++14

To my suprise the following C++ code fails to compile.

```
class InterfaceA {
public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

class InterfaceB : public InterfaceA {
public:
    virtual void Bar() = 0;
};

class ImplementationA : public InterfaceA {
public:
    void Foo() override {}
};

class ImplementationB : public ImplementationA, public InterfaceB {
public:
    void Bar() override {}
};

int main() {
    ImplementationB b;
    b.Bar();
}
```

> object of abstract class type "ImplementationB" is not allowed:
>     pure virtual function "InterfaceA::Foo" has no overrider.
>   Error C2259   'ImplementationB': cannot instantiate abstract class.

Is it possible to inherit the implementation of the pure virtual method from Implementation A without redefining the method Foo in ImplementationB as:

```
void Foo() override {
    ImplementationA::Foo();
}
```

and if not then why?

Comment: C++ is different from Java. And this has been asked several times before.

Comment: I think the answer here is better than the answers in the duplicate cited above. Those answers don't mention virtual inheritance, because the problem specified in the other question doesn't inherit from classes with a common ancestor, as the problem here does. The questions aren't really the same (and this one answered the problem I had when I found my way here, which the other doesn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a diamond problem. Therefore, you should use a virtual inheritance.

Correct code:

```
class InterfaceA {
public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

class InterfaceB : public virtual InterfaceA {
public:
    virtual void Bar() = 0;
};

class ImplementationA : public virtual InterfaceA {
public:
    void Foo() override {}
};

class ImplementationB : public ImplementationA, public InterfaceB {
public:
    void Bar() override {}
};

int main() {
    ImplementationB b;
    b.Bar();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, to achieve what you need you need to use virtual inhertiance.

Some details:
As it is now, you have two parents for your ImplementationB, each of which are independent descendents of InterfaceA. As a result, you have 2 copies of InterfaceA in your ImplementationB - one which was inherited from ImplementationA and has Foo() overridden, and another one which was inherited from InterfaceA, and does not have Foo overriddent. Virtual inheritance (not to be confused with virtual functions!) would ensure you have only one copy - the one which has everything overridden.